# How can I speed up github action runner pick Github action job?

Tags: github-actions, policy, runner

I setup two runners use github-action-controller.

```
apiVersion: actions.summerwind.dev/v1alpha1
kind: RunnerDeployment
metadata:
  name: xxxxx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict: "true"
    spec:
      labels:
      - xxxxx
      repository: xxxxxx
```

But I get the issue waiting a runer pick up this job. How can we increase the speed of runner pick up a aciton job?

I think we should setup the speed of rate for runner to pull action job, once per 20s/30s  but I am not sure.